# How to get latitude & longitude from given address on Android?

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to get latitude and longitude of particular address . How can i do this ?

Comment: I also wanna in my application.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the sample [solution](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/02/get-locationlatitude-and-longitude-from.html) to your question.

OR

```
List<Address> foundGeocode = null;
/* find the addresses  by using getFromLocationName() method with the given address*/
foundGeocode = new Geocoder(this).getFromLocationName("address here", 1);
foundGeocode.get(0).getLatitude(); //getting latitude
foundGeocode.get(0).getLongitude();//getting longitude
```

For more details [Geocoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html)

Comment: In this sample code I have to give some addresses within spinner from that i have to select anyone that means address is fixed. but i want which addr i will give through editText only for that it will go to that pace in map. How can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

```
public List<Address> getFromLocationName (String locationName, int maxResults)
```

Answer (score 1):

From a `Geocoder` object, you can call the `getFromLocation`

```
public List<Address> getFromLocation (double latitude, double longitude, int maxResults)
```

It will return a list of Address object that has a method `getLocality`

```
Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
List<Address> addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
if (addresses.size() > 0) 
    System.out.println(addresses.get(0).getLocality());
```

[for more detail](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html)

Comment: shows city name in Google Maps if  have lat,long values of a town or area

Answer (score 1):

show the location in google map from address...will get the latitude and longitude using the address...

```
Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(this);    
        List<Address> address;

  try {
            address = coder.getFromLocationName(strAddress,5);
            if (address == null) {
                return null;
            }
            Address location = address.get(0);
            location.getLatitude();
            location.getLongitude();

            p1 = new GeoPoint((int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6),
                    (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6));

            return p1;
```

strAddress is string that you pass of address. address variable is address converting and getting address.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html view this link for more detail