# getting latitude and longitude from given address

Tags: android

I tried this coding --

```
      public LatLng getLocationFromAddress(Context                  context, String strAddress) {

    Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(context);
    List<Address> address;
    LatLng p1 = null;

    try {
        // May throw an IOException
        address = coder.getFromLocationName(strAddress, 5);
        if (address == null) {
            return null;
        }
        Address location = address.get(0);
        location.getLatitude();
        location.getLongitude();

        p1 = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude() );

    } catch (IOException ex) {

        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return p1;
}
```

But getting error for getLatitude and getLongitude cannot be resloved, strAddress i pass the  address from program.
I have enable gradle:    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
Android mainfeat:

```
              <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: you need to add location run time permission and in manifest too

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get latitude & longitude from given address on Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6466369/how-to-get-latitude-longitude-from-given-address-on-android)

Answer (score 0):

You have to give permissions in your manifest file.
You can use ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION or ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION as per your requirement.

```
<uses-permission android:name=”android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION” />
<uses-permission android:name=”android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION” />
```

For more details check https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html